# Object motion detection with event triggering in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camerax, google-mlkit

Here is the goal:

- to develop an Android App with CameraX API that performs object motion detection. Any time the camera detects an object's motion it triggers an event. This is a surveillance app.
  Furthermore, there is the possibility of having various levels of sensitivity, related to movement tolerance.

From what I have seen so far the solution can go through the use of ML Kit, namely, object detection and tracking. However, my purpose is to trigger an event like sending sms, on any object motion. I think the solution may be based on Google ML Kit. I really do not know how to solve this problem.

Thanks